# Fill pandas column in df1 based on value in an interval of two columns in df2

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill out an empty column in a dataframe containing discrete sample depths (sample df). I want to scan through a second dataframe (interval df) containing depth intervals and check which interval the depth in sample df is in and then assign the value found in that depth interval in interval df to sample df . How would I go about this?

I have a dataframe of depth intervals where the top and bottom depth of the interval is defined and a value for that interval:

```
interval_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'top depth':[100,200,700],
    'bottom depth':[200,700,1000],
    'value':[15,10,20],
})
```

The second dataframe contains selected depths where I want to fill out the 'value' column based on what the value is for this interval in interval_df:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'depth':[258,300,567,858,900],
    'value':[0,0,0,0,0]
})
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'depth':[258,300,567,858,900],
    'uncertainty':[10,10,10,20,20]
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are supposed to explain how you have researched your problem and where you got stuck. Setting input and expected output without exposing prior research is not the proper way to ask on this site. Could you please elaborate  on your actual difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.cut` as your interval is dense:

```
bins = (pd.concat([interval_df['top depth'], interval_df['bottom depth']])
          .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True))
labels = interval_df['value']

sample_df['uncertainty'] = pd.cut(sample_df['depth'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
>>> sample_df
   depth uncertainty
0    258          10
1    300          10
2    567          10
3    858          20
4    900          20
```

You can also use `pd.merge_asof`:

```
>>> pd.merge_asof(sample_df, interval_df.rename(columns={'value': 'uncertainty'}),
                  left_on='depth', right_on='bottom depth', direction='forward')

   depth  value  top depth  bottom depth  uncertainty
0    258      0        200           700           10
1    300      0        200           700           10
2    567      0        200           700           10
3    858      0        700          1000           20
4    900      0        700          1000           20
```